# Redis max clients "error The operating system is not able to handle the specified number of clients, try with 10208"

Tags: linux, redis

Hi i have a problem with Redis on linux redhat, when i am trying to modify maxclients to more than 10k i have an error "error The operating system is not able to handle the specified number of clients, try with 10208"
I already have modified

ulimit -n 50000

sudo cat /etc/security/limits.conf

- soft nofile 50000
- hard nofile 50000

/etc/security/limits.d/95-redis.conf

redis soft nofile 50000

redis hard nofile 50000

/etc/systemd/system/redis.service

LimitNOFILE=50000

I restarted the serwer and nothing happend stil same error

Comment: What are the values of `net.core.somaxconn`, `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max`, `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range`, `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout`? You find them with `sysctl -A` command. Socket connections not only rely on `ulimits` as you changed, it could be depending on above flags as well.

Comment: Do you see any buffer errors with `netstat -s` & also any errors you see in `journalctl -u <redis-service-name>` & `dmesg | tail`?

Comment: net.core.somaxconn = 128 net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 32768    60999
net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max = 65536. net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 60 @harshavmb           No Errors

Comment: Can you change `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` to somewhat like `1024 65000` & `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` to `30` & `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max` to `131072`. We are basically increasing more ports for redis to use & decrease `tcp_timeout` to have more connections open. `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_max` keeps track of concurrent connections & we are doubling it.

Comment: It require a reboot after that? @harshavmb

Comment: Docs say `reboot` not required but for some reason in the past, `net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range` needed a reboot to have a broad port range. Nevertheless, I would try applying them first with `sysctl -w` to see if situation improves, otherwise, I'll change `/etc/sysctl.conf` & reboot so as to persist on reboots..

Comment: Well i checked that on test serwer where everything is working fine and all the values are the same as i metioned here, so i dont think thats the issue. Any other ideas? Maybe redis  starts with an assigned conf file which has a predefined number of hosts?